# How to find current date in the list of Date

Tags: android, date

My Date list has items in this format:

Thu Dec 30 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2021

How to pass the index to this field:

viewPager2.currentItem = datesList.indexOf(????)

I need a new fragment to open every day.

Answer (score 0):

I've made it like this (not perfect but for me it works):

```
for (i in 1..500) {
            var date:Date = cal.time
            list.add(date)
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, +1)
            date = cal.time
            datesList.add("$date")
            if (date.toSimpleString() == currentDay.toSimpleString()){
                binding!!.viewPager2.currentItem = datesList.size
            }
        }
```

Comment: great job, it will work!